# Backbone router, pushstate, and relative urls

Tags: backbone.js, pushstate, backbone-routing

I'm making my first backbone app. I have pushstate enabled. In the router I have two routes.

```
    'link1(/)' : 'link1Route',              
    'link2(/)' : 'link2Route'
```

On my link1 page, I have a link pointing to link 2 like so:

```
    <a href="link2">Link2</a>
```

I click on the link, the router takes over and I go to link2Route as expected. However, if I hover over the link, the status bar indicates that the link is at domain.com/link1/link2 rather than domain.com/link2. This is correct given the relative url structure on the link1 page. Unfortunately, if a user decides to open the link in a new window or tab, backbone's router will not take effect. This is expected since opening in a new window or tab results in a new page load from the server. The problem of course, is that domain.com/link1/link2 does not exist.

What are some ways of dealing with this situation? Thanks.

Comment: try change your anchor to <a href="/link2">Link2</a>

Comment: Woah, I think this will do it. So simple, but wasn't working for me because I didn't have virtual hosts set up and so originally it would go to localhost/link2 even though I was in localhost/backboneapp/link2. Awesome, thank you! I'll play around with it some more but it looks like this is what I need.

Answer (score 2):

As mateusmaso indicated, you need to change your link target to "/link2" (i.e. including the "/").

In addition, when implementing pushState, don't forget you need your server to respond with content if a user requests the "domain.com/link2" URL. The response can be `index.html` if you wish, but the server must return a page for that URL.

If you return `index.html` for all your Backbone-related URLs, when your Backbone app gets started the route-handling code will get fired and the proper data will be displayed.

If you want to learn more about routing and how to manage it properly without needing to pass `trigger: true` when calling `navigate`, check out pages 32-46 of this free sample pdf: http://samples.leanpub.com/marionette-gentle-introduction-sample.pdf (full disclosure, I'm the book author)

Comment: thanks, David. I'll check out your pdf. I've actually done your Marionette tutorials, they were very useful to me. I am sure the book will be the same :)

Comment: Thanks, I'm doing my best to write a book that will be useful to many levels to readers. But if you only want to learn more about routing, the sample pdf should be enough.

Answer (score 0):

You must serve the correct index.html at the server level — since this is before the JavaScript even loads on the page.

http://readystate4.com/2012/05/17/nginx-and-apache-rewrite-to-support-html5-pushstate/

Comment: I have apache rewriting already. This will cover scenarios where the page will exist. So in my example domain.com/link1 and domain.com/link2 will both work if directly loaded from a bookmark or page refresh because of the apache rewrite rules in the link you shared. But this does not take into consideration my issue which is domain.com/link1/link2 which should not exist.